# Adding Columns to paste date and skill from table vba Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have several tables pasted one after another, I am trying to add two extra columns, one for the skill name and one for the date. When i run this code, the columns are added and I can see the pointer going to each cell, but it is not assigning any values. I will appreciate your suggestions on this code.

```
Dim date_var As String
Dim skill_var As String
Dim msg_var As Integer

Sub Add_Date_Skill()
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Select

Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
If ActiveCell.Value = "Date" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Let date_var = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select

ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "Split/Skill" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Let skill_var = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select

Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = skill_var
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = date_var
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You are not writing any values into the cells unless your conditions both fail.

Comment: Solved, the Date and Split/Skills have a Colon (:) at the end!

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the Date and Split/Skills have a Colon (:) at the end!